# PHPExcel : header full of giberish

Tags: symfony, phpexcel

I wan't to extract an html table to a .xsl file. I've installed PHPExcel in symfony2, but when i just want to test it by extracting a random page to an .xls file, first part's file is full of gibberish and i really don't know why : http://images4.hiboox.com/images/2714/f657dfd1d406e941cfbe3ff9dbc10f7b.png

And below this i've got my html table.

here 's the code, thanks :

```
$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("foo");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("bar");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C1', 'Hello');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');
    echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";
    $objWriter = new \PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    //$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
    //$objWriter->save('a.xls');
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="PV AAPC"');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're not sending anything else to output. Ensure that you have no echo or print statements; no BOM headers in your script file; and no blank lines between `?>` and `<?php` tags.

You're also writing the file using the Excel2007 Writer (which generates an OfficeOpenXML-format .xlsx file) but sending the content type for a BIFF-format .xls file.

You need to send a content type header of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for an OfficeOpenXML-format `.xlsx` file (generated using the `Excel2007` Writer); or use the `Excel5` Writer if you want to create a BIFF-format `.xls` file, which requires a content type header of `application/vnd.ms-excel`

Comment: Hello, i changed the header but the gibberish persist. I found something  : if i `die;` the code before the `$objWriter->save('php://output');` everything works fine, but right after the `$objWriter->save('php://output');` those random characters come!

Comment: If you `die` before doing the `save()`, of course you won't get that "gibberish", because the `save()` is what writes that "gibberish" to php://output.... of course, you won't get your file either, because that "gibberish" ___is___ the file

Answer (score 0):

You display some debug info before sending headers.

Remove the "echo date ..." line, and it will be ok !

Comment: hello thanks for your reply, but i've still got this garbled text :/

Comment: Can you give us all the code before "$objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();" ? (for example with the inclusion of the php excel library)

Comment: Hello, there is nothing before this object. But i think i'm just going to save the file inside the folder... by using :  `$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));`